# How to show replicate number when using sapply in R?

Tags: r

Consider the function below:

```
 f = function(i) i^2
```

Now we find the output of `f` for an input vector of length 1000 (or equivalently to run `f` for 1000 replications) by:

```
output = c()
for (i in 1:1000) output[i] = f(i)
```

In the case of running time-consuming functions, we might like to know which replication we are. So we can use:

```
output = c()
for (i in 1:1000) {output[i] = f(i); cat("Replicate=", i, "\n")}
```

This gives the replicate number at the end of each replication. Now what if we use `sapply` instead of `for`:

```
 output = sapply(1:1000, function(i) f(i))
```

How can we see which replicate we are while using `sapply`?  Note that I tried adding `cat("Replicate=", i, "\n")` in the definition of `f`. This shows the replicate number, but only at the end of the entire run and not at the end of each replicate.

Comment: See [print](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html)

Comment: E.g. `sapply(1:1000, function(i) {print(paste0("Replicate=", i)); fun(i)})`

Comment: @Joseph Wood : Thank you. I tried your code, but `print` just performs as `cat` here, i.e. it shows the replication numbers at the end of the entire run but not at the end of each replicate.

Comment: You are mistaken... try running this code in your console: `sapply(1:100, function(x) {print(x); Sys.sleep(1); max(x)})`

Comment: @Joseph Wood: Yes, I got it. Your code works well! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you say you have tried it, but this code works just great for me:

```
result <-  sapply(1:1000, function(x) {
  print(x)  # cat works too
  return(x^2)
})
```

You may have forgotten the curly brackets! :-)